# How did Thomas Aquinas know which man Satan inhabited?

Tags: plot-explanation, end-of-days

The movie [*End of Days*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0146675/) from 1999 features Satan inhabiting the body of a man portrayed by [Gabriel Byrne](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabriel_Byrne).

Thomas Aquinas is a priest sent by the Vatican to protect a girl prophesied to be the mother of Satan's child.

The morning after Satan inhabits the body of an investment banker (Gabriel Byrne), Thomas Aquinas is on a rooftop shooting at him in an attempt to kill [him](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/End_of_Days_(film)).

> In late 1999, Satan possesses an investment banker (Gabriel Byrne) in
>   a restaurant; he then destroys the restaurant, killing many inside.
>   Suicidal and alcoholic former police detective Jericho Cane (Arnold
>   Schwarzenegger), depressed since his wife and daughter (Denice D.
>   Lewis and Renee Olstead respectively) were killed in contract
>   killings, works for a private security company and blames God for his
>   plight. Jericho and co-worker Bobby Chicago (Kevin Pollak) are
>   assigned to protect the possessed banker. A priest, Thomas Aquinas
>   (Derrick O'Connor), unsuccessfully tries to kill the banker.

What evidence does the movie provide informing Thomas Aquinas that Gabriel Byrne's character is in fact Satan?